# in report, repeat only certain columns after first row

Tags: ms-access, reporting

I'm tasked with replicating in Access a particular report running in a Filemaker database. The output should look like this:

```
NAME       DATE       ITEM(S)
Joe      5/2/2012     Gum
                      Tape
                      Soap
Ann      5/1/2012     Paper
Bob      5/1/2012     Pen
                      Paper
```

where the records look like this (it's a query joining the "person" and "items" tables, which have a 1:many relationship):

```
NAME       DATE       ITEM(S)
Joe      5/2/2012     Gum
Joe      5/2/2012     Tape
Joe      5/2/2012     Soap
Ann      5/1/2012     Paper
Bob      5/1/2012     Pen
Bob      5/1/2012     Paper
```

In the report, I need the first ITEM always to show up in the first, complete row; if there are more items, only the items should be listed in subsequent rows (the NAME and DATE values should not be repeated).

I'm not quite sure which tree to bark up:

- in RDL I can conditionally hide report items on a row-by-row basis... can I do that in Access reports (in Access continuous forms, I think one cannot do that -- the Visible setting applies to all rows simultaneously, I think)
- can I do this with a Group, putting the first, complete row in the Group header and the subsequent rows in the Detail section? If so, I'm not sure how I would get just the first item in the header, and how to suppress that first item in the details section
- other ideas? do I need to think about a different record source, or sources?

The only thing I've managed so far is to group on the person, with the NAME and DATE in the Group Header, and then put all of the items in the detail, but that's not exactly what I have been asked to do.

Thanks in anticipation of "a-ha!".

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's the same in the reports, you can't apply conditional formatting the way you're able to in RDL.
2. This seems like the natural answer.  It's essentially a grouping operation, so group by name and date, and put those two in the header, then put the items in the detail.  The only thing is that, as I think you noted, the items would be offset by one row relative to what you're being asked.
3. You can put conditional logic in the query of course, but I don't think that works here, because the show/hide logic depends on the group query.  See #2.

Comment: Yeah, but it's precisely that row-offset that I'm asking how to avoid... no more tricks up your sleeve?

Comment: @GISmatters I just re-read my question and realized how unhelpful it is :P.  I think the only way might be to use a sub-report.  Group on name/date from main to the sub, and the sub would contain the items.  That way you can lay it out however you like.

Comment: Ah, I haven't used sub-reports... but I bet (as your answer implies) they'll work just like sub-forms: a single control that I can drop _alongside_ the NAME and DATE controls that will show all the items, shrinking or growing as needed? That sounds very promising... I'll circle back shortly to credit you when/if it works...

Answer (score 6):

1. Add a group by on Name
2. Put **all** the fields in the detail
3. Turn Hide Duplicates on all the fields

The point of putting the Group by on the name is to stop Bob's dates and items from being hidden by Ann's dates and items.

As an aside the same technique works for Crystal and Jasper reports.

**Layout view**
[image]

**Design View**
[image]

Comment: +1 How is it that I have been working in Access for years and never knew that this property existed?

Comment: I also did not know about Hide Duplicates -- very useful! I'll have to experiment to see if it works for my needs, which are more complex than the simple example I gave. I actually have multiple columns like "items" that need to repeat (Parcel, FundingCode, Acres, and Cost), but in any individual column duplicates would be legitimate (e.g., two parcels might use the same FundingCode, or one parcel might be split-funded). My guess is HideDuplicates might not handle this properly, but I'll check. Meanwhile, @dbaseman's sub-report suggestion works well.

Comment: @GISmatters Its always good to have many tools in the toolbox and I'm not overly concerned about the Answer acceptance. Who knows you may end up using both techniques then which do you choose. I would note that one problem with subreports (another technique you can find in just about every reporting tool) is that they can be a perf problem as the lend themselves to an "n + 1 selects problem".

Answer (score 0):

In jaspersoft iReport 4.6.0

1. Choose "add Report Group" and then group with one field(eg.name)
   that you want to show once.
2. You need to add all the field in Detail band
3. Change in the properties of "print repeated values" (checkbox) off, which you want to
   show once.